# Alignment algorithm

Tags: statistics

So I'm trying to figure out to calculate some sort of alignment of strength score for a group of people's selections on various values.  In this case, there are 36 values, each person selects gives 9 of them a +1, and 9 -1.  The rest are just zero.  What would be the best way to figure out how "aligned" a group of people are?

What would this type of calculation be called so I can learn more about it.

Thanks.

PS, sorry for my ignorance, I'm a math idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One choice is to count the number of positions where they agree. Another is to add up the square of the differences between two scores. This will count positions where one said $+1$ and the other said $-1$ four times as strongly as one where one said $0.$  neither is more right than the other, it depends if you think the $+1$ vs. $-1$ is more important.